# Logic gate out of boolean expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How do I make a logic gate out of this expression

```
X'(Y'+Z')
```

Update below is a screen shot of my circuit corresponding to the equation

[image]

Comment: But writing a truth table?

Comment: and then what do I do after that

Comment: @Arthur check my post